# Is refraction unpredictable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, refraction, photon-emission

Let us take a simplified version of refraction, where light slows down because of atom absorption and re-emission. Let us denote this time as $\tau_{emission}$, do we have a function $\tau_{emission}(\lambda)$, if so are there any references for it?

I think the above statement is wrong, what I was feeling was we care about the hamiltonian matrix of the excited atom statement. Say for a wavelength the resulting electron cloud is symmetric, it would take longer to emit. But, I feel because of the uncertainty principle, we cant be sure about the prediction of this time, as we don't really know where the wave-function collapses to.

If indeed we cannot predict the time taken, then for say a isotropic slab will light have different velocities throughout the slab?

**I am taking a thin slab, so we cant say statistically it evens out**

Comment: If you want to understand refraction, get yourself some lenses and prisms. Experiment with them. Do they behave predictably?

Comment: @JohnDoty they definitely do, but they arent agreeing with my model, please explain why. You can say statistically it evens out but for thin slab that doesnt work

Comment: @SteveSaban No it doesnt

Comment: Refraction is a coherent phenomenon. No wavefunction collapse.

Comment: @JohnDoty So u are saying we can predict with **absolute certainty** the reabsorption time

Comment: You can't even specify when the wave arrives. But what you can predict is the precise amplitude/phase relationship between the incoming and outgoing waves. Then, the squared amplitude of the outgoing wave predicts the expected rate of random photon detections at any particular place. Complementarity.

Comment: This seems to be about the effect of Rayleigh scattering on the index of refraction. https://site.physics.georgetown.edu/~vankeu/webtext2/Workspace/Rayleigh%20scattering/Rayleigh%20scattering.htm#:~:text=Index%20of%20Refraction%20(n)%3A,it%20travels%20through%20the%20medium.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of light incident on an atom, refraction is forward scattering of photons, and is associated with a phase shift.   That phase shift,
and the wavelength of light, defines a distance (and, with the
speed of light, thus, a time) which is a kind of delay of
the light wave.   Actual absorption/emission is not the
usual case, because atomic allowed electron energies are
few, and rather than orbital transitions, the light
interaction is due to orbits themselves being changed by the applied
field (Stark effect).   Refraction in dilute gas is largely unrelated to spectrum features of the gas atoms,
and associated absorption/emission delay.

In practical terms, though, much light interaction with matter is
not with individual atoms, but with liquids or solids that have
chemical bonds and near-neighbor perturbations of the outer electrons;
electron bands consist of mobile charge that dominates the
response to visible light.